# Better Method For Infequently Changed Configuration Information Used By Multiple Modules

Tags: python, configuration, import

I'm struggling to decide on the "best" way to provide configuration data to a number of sysadmin scripts that do things like manage backups, archives, etc.

The two methods that I have been using during testing are constants in the scripts (not at all great for production but easy for testing) and using configparser to have the info in a single file.

I'm looking at an alternative of putting everything into a single module like this:

configurations.py

```
import re
# Regular expression object to use in matching with file names
FILE_NAME_MATCH_PATTERN = re.compile(
    '''([A-Z@~1-9]{4})     # Group-1: 4 uppercase letters for the show code
    _                 # if they are followed by an underscore
    (\d{2}\.?\d{3})   # Group-2: either ##.### or ##### (remove the . to get a final file name!
    _                 # if they are followed by an underscore
    ([A-Z](?=[._ ]))   # Group-3: a SINGLE uppercase letter IF it is followed by a " ", "." or an "_" only
    _?                # but, since we may or may not have the _ we need to look for it
    (.*)              # Group-4: IF there is anything between A_ and .ext we capture it here
    \.(.+)$           # Group-5: The file extension, of any length
    ''', re.VERBOSE)  # DESIGNED TO WORK WITH RE.MATCH AT THE BEGINNING OF A STRING!
WATCHED_FOLDER_PATH = '/Users/ops/Desktop/first_drop'
OUTPUT_FOLDER_PATH = '/Users/ops/Desktop/slicer_watched'
SECONDS_TO_WAIT_FOR_IMAGES = 5  # 5 for testing, 60 for production
SECONDS_TO_WAIT_FOR_UPLOADS = 5  # 5 for testing, 20 for production
SECONDS_TO_WAIT_BETWEEN_FOLDER_CHECKS = 1  # 1 for testing, 120 for production
```

and using from configurations import * 
But, I'm slightly worried about name collisions. I know that I can do configurations.OUTPUT_FOLDER_PATH (etc.), just a little messy looking. Perhaps,

```
from configurations import SECONDS_TO_WAIT_FOR_IMAGES
```

etc.

Ideally, there is a single config file that might get used by many different routines but that presents the issue of making sure that the config file path is part of each script (another constant) while the import method only requires me to put the configurations.py file into the pythonpath on the machine.

Surely this is a problem that has been discussed to death but my Google-Fu has let me down.

Comment: Could use a dictionary? Not sure what's wrong with `configurations.OUTPUT_FOLDER_PATH` apart from line length issues which would annoy me as well.

Comment: Had not thought of a dict. Main issue there would be that a dict would be more likely to get messed up if you allow a "user" to modify it. That is one of the good things about a config file too - no quotes, not muss, very hard to mess up.

Comment: Yeah, easy to miss a `,` or `:`. You could make smaller classes like `SecondsToWait` which has `FOR_IMAGES` etc which makes it easier to deal with that pretty much how we dealt with a similar thing a work